# firebase auth browserSessionPersistence is undefined

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to change the type of auth persistence based on the user choice.
I've tried to set the persistence to the type of browserSessionPersistence but it give me this error.
I'm on react native and I'm using firebase v9

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[0], "@firebase/util").getModularInstance(auth).setPersistence')
```

Here is my import and the code where i set persistence
(auth is working fine and the code of setpersistence is run before login that works)

```
import {setPersistence,browserSessionPersistence} from 'firebase/auth';

setPersistence(browserSessionPersistence)
```

I tried to console log the value of browserSessionPersistence and I get that its undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Some Firebase JavaScript SDK features are only compatible with browsers only.

`browserSessionPersistence` is only supported on web.

You should either use `inMemoryPersistence` or `browserLocalPersistence` within React Native.

| Namespaced Version V8 | Modular Version V9 |
| --- | --- |
| `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL` | `browserLocalPersistence` |
| `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION` | `browserSessionPersistence` |
| `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE` | `inMemoryPersistence` |

More details at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#supported_types_of_auth_state_persistence

Comment: I tried using browserLocalPersistence but I still get it undefined

Comment: Did you tried `inMemoryPersistence`

Comment: inMemoryPersistence is the only one that is not undefined, with console log I get only that is a function